# Give the distribution of an asymptotically Normal statistic, conditional on a function of sample ranks, and describe regression parameters

Tags: references, nonparametric, conditional-expectation, ranks, conditional-distribution

I'd like to write the following, about conditioning a normal r.v. on a rank statistic, but I'm unable to recall a specific theorem or theorems I can cite:

"Let $\hat{\rho}$ be an asymptotically normally-distributed statistic computed on IID bivariate normal sample $(X, Y)$ with population correlation $\rho$. Let $\hat{\eta}$ be a discrete statistic computed on the relative ranks of $Y$ given the ranks of $X$. Because $\hat{\eta}$ is strictly a function of sample ranks, the distribution of $\hat{\rho}|\hat{\eta}$ is asymptotically normal for all $\hat{\eta}$, and the regression of $E(\hat{\rho}|\hat{\eta})$ on $\hat{\eta}$ is asymptotically linear with intercept equal to $\rho$ and slope independent of $\rho$."

First, I should confirm: Is this stated correctly? Second, if correct, what theorems/references can I cite? BTW: I believe the linearity of the regression follows from linearity of expectation.